# How to get the size of the intersection of two arrays in MongoDB using Python

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, aggregation, intersection

I have several documents stored in MongoDB which each have an array of twitter account id's. I need to have mongoDB return the size of the intersection of two of these arrays.

The documents look like this:

```
{
    'screen_name': 'BBC',
    'name': 'British Broadcasting Company',
    'twitter_id' = '2139471834'
    'followers' = [] # This array will likely have millions of elements
}
{
    'screen_name': 'TheEconomist',
    'name': 'The Economist',
    'twitter_id' = '213945674'
    'followers' = [] # This array will likely have millions of elements
}
```

I would like the aggregation pipelines to return the size of the intersection of the two arrays. I have tried different methods of returning the size of the intersection and none have worked. The closest I have gotten is this query:

```
db.<collection>.aggregate(
[ 
  { $match : 
    { $or : 
      [ 
        {'screen_name': 'TheEconomist' }, 
        {'screen_name': 'BBC'} 
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: 
    {'num_common_followers': 
      {$size: 
        { $setIntersection: 
          ['$followers']
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

However, this does not reference the 'followers' field from each of the two documents which pass the $match stage. Therefore, it seems like I either need to find a way to reference the 'followers' field from each document, or pass a single document with the two arrays to the $project stage. I would love an answer, but also any suggestions on better ways to do this function. Thanks in advance!